# Bottom align React Bootstrap Card.Img

Tags: css, reactjs

I am beginner web developer and try to do small project with React & React-bootstrap.

I have some cards, and would like to align the images within them on the bottom. I have illustrated in the below image the current situation and how I would like to re-arrange the smaller image :
[image]

My code:

```
const Catalog = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" border="light">
      <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant="bottom" />
      </a>

      <Card.Body>
        <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <Card.Title as="div" className="py-3 text-left">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </a>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Can someone give me some hints on how I can accomplish that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is a great solution for this.

- Applying `display: flex` makes the parent a flex container
- `align-items: flex-end` is what causes the child items to align themselves to the bottom edge of the parent

This is an abstracted example, but you should be easily able to bring this concept back to styling your `<Row />` and `<Card />` components.

```css
.row {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 50%;
}

.card--tall {
  background-color: #fc0;
  height: 200px;
}

.card--short {
  background-color: #f00; 
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card card--tall"></div>
  <div class="card card--short"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @simmer, as I understand this aligns all cards to the flex-end. My problem is that I need to arrange the images only and have the cards aligned to the top and the same size.  I

Comment: I have made a simple html page in code sandbox showing my problem : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-gareth-xdubc?file=/index.html.  -  Basically I would like cards to be the same size as in this example, but images to be alligned on the bottom edge within all cards.

Comment: Ah, that's a much different issue (for future reference, it would have been helpful to include that information about in your question, as it greatly affects the answer). Short answer is that you'll need to wrap your image elements in a containing element, then either set those containing elements to a fixed height or use javascript to find the height of the tallest one and set the heights of the other elements to match that height.